# CFBuilder / ColdFusion : Why are there no files after my Dreamweaver Import

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I have recently inherited a directory of ColdFusion code developed in Dreamweaver. After downloading the source from svn into a local development directory, I attempted to follow the instructions I found in several places online for Importing a Dreamweaver site into a project, using the Existing Folder as New Project option (since it was never previously a CFBuilder project, just Dreamweaver), I assigned the CF Nature to the root in the Navigator window. However, when I attempt to drop the tree below the root, no files appear - and the little > arrow is even gone, as if there are no files.
What should I be looking at here? Obviously it lacks something that tells it all the files in the project. It is odd, because when I select the root of the directory where all the source files are "ZZZ Master Website", it creates another directory INSIDE that directory, also called "ZZZ Master Website". That's where the .project and settings files show up. I feel like I'm missing something.

FWIW, I'm no CF guy - I'm inheriting this because that resource is no longer available. So... be patient - I'm trying to come up to speed here.

Thanks for any help in advance!

duncand

Comment: If the site is already in SVN - what do you hope to get out of the legacy dreamweaver stuff?

Comment: Ummm... guess I didn't communicate very well.  I am trying to get a project in CFBuilder I can work on. Right now, I have the root folder, but there are no files (in CFBuilder - they're all there on disk). I believe IMPORT is supposed to recreate a project from the folders, but it doesn't seem to be working. Looking for assistance.

Comment: Ok ... so the secret here is your SVN setup. Make sure that you have builder set up correctly to connect to your SVN. Then you create a project to a blank folder, then you check out your SVN code. I just don't know where dreamweaver fits here? I don't think it's relevant :)

Comment: Thanks Mark. Dreamweaver is only relevant in that the "project" was previousy maintained as a "site" under Dreamweaver. As I don't have Dreamweaver, I am trying to get a project set up that understands all the files in the project.

Comment: I can see what you're suggesting - but - what if there was no SVN? What if all I have is just files in a directory structure on a disk? Anyway, assume SVN is not in the mix either - just a directory structure on disk that used to be managed through Dreamweaver. Is there any way to get CFBuilder to consume that structure?

Comment: It's eclipse. Create a project in a working directory and dump the code into the folder, then map to your local CF install. If you want to use debugging etc you will have to set up your server instance in CF Builder. 

But if it were me I would reverse it. I would set up SVN (or GIT), add all my files first to SVN, then use CFB + SVN to set up the files. That way I have the benefit of source control.

Comment: Dreamweaver "sites" were connected to deployment concepts. You would work on a site and it would keep code synched between dev and production. In this case you want source control to handle that, not your IDE.